# Contar registros del SELECT

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un SELECT donde quiero ver si existe la posibilidad de contar los registros encontrados en una columna, les paso el codigo para poder explicarme mejor:

```
$sql = "SELECT pcu_cuentas.JNombre, pcu_cuentas.Dinero, pcu_cuentas.DineroBanco, pcu_cuentas.CuentaBanco, pcu_email.Coins, pcu_locales.NombreLocal
            FROM pcu_cuentas 
            INNER JOIN pcu_email
                ON pcu_email.ID = pcu_cuentas.PlayerID
            INNER JOIN pcu_locales
                ON pcu_cuentas.JNombre = pcu_locales.Propietario
            WHERE pcu_email.ID = ?";
```

Quiero que del campo "pcu_locales.NombreLocal" poder contar todos los registros encontrados para detectar cuantos locales tiene el usuario, pero no encuentro una solución.

Comment: Tu pregunta es confusa. El total de registros equivale al total de filas encontradas.

Comment: Exacto. Quiero saber cuantos Locales tienen Propietario el nombre de la cuenta, para contar cuantos locales tiene el usuario.